# How do I read from stdin a text and write it to a file using low level file processing?

Tags: c, stdin

I tried using the following code to read a text from the keyboard and write it into the file *text.dat*. The file was created but it was empty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[201];
    int n,f = open("text.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    while (fgets(s,200,stdin) != NULL)
        write(f, s,sizeof(s));
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you might need to flush the data. any way have you tried debugging?

Comment: Use `strlen(s)` instead of `sizeof(s)`. Other than that, what did you do to determine that the file was "empty"?

Comment: I just noticed that the .dat file created was read-only for some reason. It seems to work now.

Comment: open() needs a third argument if the file is to be created. Try 0644, for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write(f, s, strlen(s))`
Though I'd use `read()` instead of `fgets()` and used its result instead of `strlen()`

Answer (score 0):

The `write` is wrong. Try this:

```
write(f, s, sizeof(s));
```

The second parameter should be a pointer to the beginning of `s`. What you're actually passing is a pointer to the pointer.

While you're at it, get rid of that unused `int n`:

```
int f = open("text.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
```

**Edited to add**

Your `write()` *must* use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` - you're probably writing out uninitialized junk, which makes it *appear* that the file is empty.

```
write(f, s, strlen(s));
```

Comment: Nope, still not writing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening file in wrong way. Try `open("text.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0666 );`

P.S.
You simply don't have write access to file.